# How to loop through an associative array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

Lets assume I have the following:

```
$times = array();
    for($month = $current_month; $month <= $end_month; $month++) {
        $first_minute = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1);
        $last_minute = mktime(23, 59, 0, $month, date('t', $first_minute));
        $times[$month] = array($first_minute, $last_minute);
    }
```

I now need to loop through all the `$months` but I am not sure how I can achieve this.

I have tried `foreach()` but that requires I enter a value for $month. We are assuming the value is not clear.

Comment: How do you expect any of that code to work when you don't have `$months` defined? Or `$current_month`, `$end_month`... Your code or your example is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you need to loop through `$times`?

A simple `foreach` will do...

```
foreach ($times as $month => $mins) {
  // $month = the month
  // $mins[0] = first minute
  // $mins[1] = last minute
}
```

Comment: no worries, don't forget to click accept on the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Can try using `foreach()` like this

```
foreach($times as $month=>$val){
    echo 'Month: ' .  $month . ' ';
    echo 'First Minute: ' . $val[0] . ' ';
    echo 'last Minute: ' . $val[1];
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use [Datetime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead?

```
$end_month = 12;
$times = [];
$oneMonth = new DateInterval('P1M');
$dt = new Datetime('midnight first day of'); // 2014-12-01T00:00:00+00:00

while($dt->format('m') <= $end_month) {
    $firstSecond = $dt->getTimestamp();
    $dt->add($oneMonth); // 2015-01-01T00:00:00+00:00
    $lastSecond = $dt->getTimestamp() -1;

    $times[$dt->format('m')] = [$firstSecond, $lastSecond];
}

foreach ($times as $month => $seconds) {
    // ...
}
```

But you could only work with Datetime object:

```
while($dt->format('m') <= $end_month) {
    $times[] = clone $dt;
    $dt->add($oneMonth);
}

foreach ($times as $month) {
    echo $month->format('m'), // 12
         $month->getTimestamp();
}
```